# Unable to get my three.js scene when deployed through react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have been trying to setup my plain JavaScript `three.js` scene by loading `.obj` and `.mtl` files using `ReactJS`.

However, I'm facing an issue while loading `.obj` and `.mtl` files using  Facebook's `create-react-app` boilerplate.  It always throws an error stating:

> `unexpected line <!DOCTYPE html>`

I have tried:

1. loading the scripts tags from `componentWillMount`.
2. importing the `three.js` scene and its associated files in the same folder.

Comment: You need to provide more details, such as the HTML of your React app.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are trying to serve your `.obj` and `.mtl` file from a local development server.  Often local development servers for single-page apps are designed to respond to all requests with the HTML of the single page app.  These apps use special locations for serving static files.  You need to follow [the directions for including static files using create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system) (place the files in the `public` folder.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried %PUBLIC_URL%/, compononentDidMount(), tried adding script tags in the header and also with settimeout after 5 seconds again the error remains the name.

Have a look at this html fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9bLzsqwr/

Comment: What is `%PUBLIC_URL%`?  Where are the `.obj` and `.mtl` files?

Comment: as you shared the link of "the directions for including static files" in your above comment, to place the files in my public folder.  I have tried loading my .obj and .mtl files in a similar way and with the timeout as well but it throws the same error. Kindly have a look at this updated fiddle for the way I which i'm loading the files. https://jsfiddle.net/9bLzsqwr/4/

Comment: The public folder is a local folder on your laptop that create-react-app has setup to serve static files from.  There is no such thing on JSFiddle.  Where did you get the name `%PUBLIC_URL%`?  Why do you expect that it will work on JSFiddle?  If you want JSFiddle to serve static files I think you need to upload them as external resources, or use links to URLs on the web where those files exist.

Comment: i understand, 1. the js fiddle which I'm using is only for reference purpose to show the HTML here. 
2. i tried the variable PUBLIC_URL to call the static files as you suggested in this link. 

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system

Comment: Okay, I see.  I don't know how create-react-app handles `PUBLIC_URL`, but it will only work on the build system created on your development machine by create-react-app.  It will not work in a JSFiddle.

Comment: So when you load your app locally in a browser, what does `%PUBLIC_URL%/js/pace.min.js` become?  Do you get the same error as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Here is my application's folder structure on my local system. https://ibb.co/mL4wiR ,all my webgl related files resides in js folder which is in components folder.I imported all the files in my component to render the scene,however it throws the same error.

Comment: Is the green "js" folder where all those third-party scripts are located?  Move that into the "public" folder.

Comment: yes the js folder has the third-party script, also tried by moving the folder to public and accessing from there but its the same response. the pace.min.js doesn't throw any error as such, the error is mainly with the other scripts.

Comment: Okay, well if one of your scripts is loading fine and the others are not, then you must figure out what is different about them.

Comment: when i try to load the similar kind of file from cdn ,i get an error stating refused to execute script from "cdn link" because its MIME type('text/Plain')is not executable,and strict MIME type checking is enabled.So,do i need to make any configuration in the webpack devconfig file??.

Comment: Update:I have added my 3D scene in the create-react-app which throws an error THREE is not defined no-undef.Please have a look github.com/priyakrishnadev/webglapp.git

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the script tags from `componentDidMount`? Maybe when `componentWillMount` is executing, the element which your renderer.domElement will append to is not mounted yet.

Comment: as you suggested i have tried with componentDidMount as well. have a look at the way i load the files in this htm https://jsfiddle.net/9bLzsqwr/